# Maven: local dependency installed not found

Tags: maven

This is my project structure:

```
$ ls
pom.xml
README.md
rep-digital-api
rep-digital-common
```

So, `rep-digital-api` has `rep-digital-common` as dependency.

I first install succesfully `rep-digital-common`:

```
mvn -pl rep-digital-common clean package install
```

The problem appears when I'm trying to tun my `rep-digital-api` spring-boot service:

```
mvn clean package -pl rep-digital-api           
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building rep-digital-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.417 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-13T15:35:28+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/68M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project rep-digital-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

**EDIT**

Parent pom.xml fragment:

```
<modules>
    <module>rep-digital-common</module>
    <module>rep-digital-api</module>
</modules>
```

I've took a look on my local repositori. The package seems to be installed:

```
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/net/gencat/transversal/repositori/digital/rep-digital-common/
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  maven-metadata-local.xml
```

My `~/.m2/settings.xml` fragment:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
</settings>
```

**EDIT 2**

Parent pom.xml is:

```
<groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
<artifactId>rep-digital</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

I've realized `mvn` is telling me that parent's `pom.xml` can't be resolved:

> Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: It did not find `net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`(your error message). Which artifact is this? Is it in your local repository?

Comment: It's a module of my parent pom.xml. I first installed it using `mvn clean package install`, but it's not picked up.

Comment: Try to clean all downloaded dependencies and and run mvn install -U

Comment: I've took a look on my local repositori. The package seems to be installed... (see post)

Comment: I've edited post again.  It seems `mvn` is not able to pick up parent's `pom.xml`

Comment: If you have a multi module build you have to install at least once all modules which means running from root `mvn clean install` afterwards you can select modules via `mvn clean install -pl ..` otherwise you are missing dependencies which will never work...